# Read in csv data for multiBarHorizontalChart in NVD3?

Tags: csv, nvd3.js

I'd like to visualise data in a "multiBarHorizontalChart" in NVD3 and read the data from a .csv file.

I'm struggling to get the data in the right format. According to NVD3.org the format for multiBarHorizontalChart has to be:

```
[
  {
    "key": "Series 1",
    "color": "#d67777",
    "values": [
      { 
        "label" : "Group A" ,
        "value" : -1.8746444827653
      } , 
      { 
        "label" : "Group B" ,
        "value" : -8.0961543492239
      }
    ]
  },
```

The code that I'm using is below. Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
d3.csv("File.csv", function (error, csv) {
  if (error) return console.log("there was an error loading the csv: " + error);
  console.log("there are " + csv.length + " elements in my csv set");

var mmm = ["pre_ineq","post_ineq"];

for (var i = 0; i < mmm.length; i++) {
 myall[i].values.label = csv.map(function(d) { return [ d["label"] ]; });
 myall[i].values.value = csv.map(function(d) { return [ +d[mmm[i]] ]; });

//or?  myall[i].values = csv.map(function(d) { return [ label=d["label"], +d[mmm[i]] ]; });

};


var chart;
nv.addGraph(function() {
  var chart = nv.models.multiBarHorizontalChart()
      .x(function(d) { return d.label })
      .y(function(d) { return d.value })
      .margin({top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 50, left: 175})
      .showValues(true)
      .tooltips(false)
      .showControls(false);

  chart.yAxis
      .tickFormat(d3.format(',.2f'));

  d3.select('#chart1')
      .datum(myall)
    .transition().duration(500)
      .call(chart);

  nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

  return chart;
});

});
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess you should do something like

```
for (var i = 0; i < mmm.length; i++) {
    myall[i].values = csv.map(function(d) { 
        return { "label": d["label"], "value": +d[mmm[i]] }; 
    });
};
```

But it's not tested.